# Error while running PJSUA android sample application

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

I am trying to build & run pjsua sample app of pjsip and have successfully build it.

I have followed this [PJSIP](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) tutorial.

- ID : sip:150@123.12.xxx.123:5060
- Registrar : sip:123.12.xxx.123:5060
- Proxy : sip:123.12.xxx.123:5060
- Username : 150
- Password : 111111

I am able to register as i am getting "Registration Successful" as response on dialog screen and 200 ok response in log.

I added a buddy with URI as sip:151 (username). It is being shown in list.

When i select buddy from list and try to make call i get a crash with following error log.

```
10-24 10:57:13.644: A/libc(7553): ../src/pjmedia/sdp_neg.c:110: pjmedia_sdp_neg_create_w_local_offer: assertion "(status=pjmedia_sdp_validate(local))==PJ_SUCCESS" failed
10-24 10:57:13.644: A/libc(7553): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 7699 (Thread-21990)
```

I am not sure where i am going wrong but i am not able to establish a sip call with my sip server.

I have tested my server with CSipSimple app available from this [link](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) and it is working fine with it.

Comment: Have you solved that? I am stuck in this error...

Comment: Did u find any solution ? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Just a theory, but maybe try adding him using the URI of "sip:151@*YourServer*"

Answer (score 0):

Same crash and lot of search bring me to this [post](http://www.spinics.net/lists/pjsip/msg18883.html).
I'm build `pjsip` without video codecs and size of `CodecInfoVector` was 0.

```
        CodecInfoVector mCodecInfoVectorV = mEndpoint.videoCodecEnum();
        for (int i = 0; i < mCodecInfoVectorV.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(mCodecInfoVectorV.get(i).getCodecId() + "\n" +
                    mCodecInfoVectorV.get(i).getDesc());
        }
```

So i had to enable video codecs and re-build `pjsip` even if they are isn't used. And after that i've been able to make call